# SQL update query not cooperating

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, mysqli

I am adding a save/update button to the bottom of my editing form on my admin panel. For some reason, whenever I make a change to the form and click save it just reloads the page with no changes made. I also noticed that ONLY when I try to run the code from the pages.php file(runnning from index then clicking pages is fine) it says:

> Undefined variable: dbc in
>   C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Xampp\htdocs\jakefordsite\admin\content\pages.php
>   on line 12
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in
>   C:\Users\Jake\Desktop\Xampp\htdocs\jakefordsite\admin\content\pages.php
>   on line 12

I can get rid of this error by declaring a new $dbc(databaseconnection) variable in pages.php, but I still have the same problem updating my form data.

PAGES.PHP:

```
<?php ## Page Manager ?>

<h2>Page Manager</h2>

<div class="col sidebar">

    <ul>

        <?php

           $q = "SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY name ASC"; 
           $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

           if ($r)
           {
                while ($link = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
                {
                    echo '<li><a href="?page=pages&id='.$link['id'].'">'.$link['name'].'</a></li>';
                }
           }

        ?>

    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col editor">

    <?php

     if (isset($_POST['submitted']) == 1) { 

            $q = "UPDATE pages SET title='$_POST[title]', name='$_POST[name]', body='$_POST[body]', WHERE id = '$_POST[id]'"; 
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

     }

     if (isset($_GET['id'])) { 

            $q = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = '$_GET[id]' LIMIT 1";
;  
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
            $opened = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);


    ?>

        <form action="?page=pages&id=<?php echo $opened['id'] ?>" method="post">

            <p><label>Page title: </label><input type="text" size="30" name="title" value="<?php echo $opened['title']?>"></p>
            <p><label>Page name:</label> <input type="text" size="30" name="name" value="<?php echo $opened['name']?>"></p> 

            <label>Page body: </label><br>
            <textarea name="body" cols="30" rows="8"><?php echo $opened['body'] ?></textarea>

               <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1"/>
               <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $opened['id'] ?>"/>

             <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes"/></p>

        </form>

    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

INDEX.PHP:

```
<?php
// Setup document:
include('config/setup.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php //echo $page_title; ?>JakeForDesign - Admin Panel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="wrap_overall">

    <div class="header"> <?php head(); ?> </div>

    <div class="nav_main"> <?php nav_main(); ?> </div>

    <div class="content"> <?php include('content/'.$pg.'.php'); ?> </div>

    <div class="footer"> <?php footer(); ?> </div>

</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

SETUP.PHP

```
<?php
## Setup Document

// host(or location of the database), username, //password, database name

$dbc = @mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password', 'main') OR die ('Could not connect to the database because: '. mysqli_connect_error() );

include('Functions/sandbox.php');
include('Functions/template.php');

if (isset($_GET['page']) == '')
{
    $pg = 'home';       
}
else
{
    $pg = $_GET['page'];
}

$page_title = get_page_title($dbc, $pg);

?>
```

Comment: May be you should not load your database connect for $dbc

Comment: You're using mysqli, which supports parametrized queries. Why are you doing string interpolation, which allows SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

on **Pages.php** you have

```
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

`$q` is fine but you have not mentioned `$dbc`

on your `setup page`, create a class for connection, declareing a `connection method` and then, on **PAGES.PHP**:

```
$db_obj =  new setup();  /* create object for setup class */
$dbc = $db_obj -> connect_db();/* call connection method */
```

Comment: dont forget to include `setup page` in `pages.php`